# php://input is empty on my server but is not when I run on xampp

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to figure out why `file_get_contents("php://input");` is empty when I run it on my server (iPage) but it works just fine on xampp. I read some posts but I found no answer. I made sure that there is no log errors and that `allow_url_fopen=On`. I am also aware that it does not work with `multipart/form-data`

Someone can point me in the right direction!

```
var ajax = function(object){
    var oo, xhr;
    oo = j2.extend({
        method: 'get',
        credentials: false,
        beforesend: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }, object);


    if("XMLHttpRequest" in window){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            oo.complete && oo.complete(xhr);

            if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300){
                oo.success && oo.success(xhr);  
            }
            else if(xhr.status >= 400 && xhr.status < 600){
                oo.error && oo.error(xhr);
            }   
        }
        else if((xhr.readyState === 3) && (oo.loading)){
            oo.loading(xhr);
        }
        else if((xhr.readyState === 2) && (oo.headers)){
            oo.headers(xhr)
        }
        else if((xhr.readyState === 1) && (oo.received)){
            oo.received(xhr);
        }
    }

    xhr.open(oo.method, oo.action, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = oo.credentials;

    j2.foreach(oo.beforesend, function(v, k){
        xhr.setRequestHeader(k, v);
    });

    xhr.send(oo.data);
};
```

---

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

---

```
var link = 'http://127.0.0.1/products/115';
j2.put({ action: link
    , data: 'price=78.59'
    , beforesend: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Auth-Token': '879vmc8749c4m8957mf9857fm986fg'
    }
    , error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
    , success: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the context that the line is being used in?  The problem might not be `file_get_contents("php://input")` but another abnormality ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As mentioned I am able to run it on XAMPP. Everything works perfect! Even if I remove everything and I simply type file_get_contents("php://input") it shows empty!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you get back what? There's also not enough code.

Comment: Empty. As a matter of fact I just tried file_exists('php://input') and it returns false!

Comment: Just out of curiosity .. You are `PUT`-ing data and not `POST`-ing right?  `file_get_contents("php://input")` retrieves `PUT` data.

Comment: Yes. I am doing a PUT request, and I aware that this does not work with POST or GET. As I mentioned it works in XAMPP

Comment: But without the rest of your code, we don't know whether you are PUTTING or POSTING ...  Without the rest of your code including the PUT statement your replies are going to be limited.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited it. It is working, because if I echo it shows that it is executing the file, but the php://input does not even exist

Comment: I just tried changing the domain and I noticed that if I change my domain for localhost it shows file_get_contents("php://input") is populated. This is somewhat weird as I am running the request on my shared server and I am setting the url to PUT as localhost rather than mydomain.com